# What are these Mites/Aphids on Bamboo?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, bamboo

We live in Pune, India which has a dry climate.
We see these aphids or mites on the leaves of our bamboo.
The round cocoons are on the under side of the leaves. (Is cocoon the correct word?)

The whole plant:
[image: The whole plant]

An Infected Leaf:
[image: An infected leaf]

Here are some photos and a video taken using iPhone 7 + 60x-100x Pocket microscope:
[image: Under the Microscope]
[image: Under the Microscope]
[image: Under the Microscope]
[image: Under the Microscope]

We applied Neem oil to the underside of all the leaves, then wiped off the spores using a wet cloth (if that is the correct word?). It is, of course, a tedious job and it is impossible to clean each and every leaf completely. A few days later, we observed some damage to some of the leaves - probably due to application of Neem Oil . Here is a photo:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like scale/mealy bug insects to me. Nice gif of the crawler stage.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect